# How to stop tkinter from text wrapping?

Tags: python, tkinter

Anybody know why my message formats itself in this way?
[Tkinter GUI Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5uDD.png)

I would like the text of the colors to remain on one line each.

```
label = Message(root, text="RED", relief=FLAT).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
Red = Entry(root, width=5, borderwidth=1).grid(row=0,column=1)

label = Message(root, text="BLUE", relief=FLAT,).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
Blue = Entry(root, width=5, borderwidth=1,).grid(row=1,column=1)

label = Message(root, text="GREEN", relief=FLAT).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
Green = Entry(root, width=5, borderwidth=1,).grid(row=2,column=1)

label = Message(root, text="LIGHT ID", relief=FLAT).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
LightNum = Entry(root, width=5, borderwidth=1,).grid(row=3,column=1)
```

Comment: Why do you use `Message` instead of `tk.Label`?

Comment: Just an fyi: `.grid` returns `None`. So `label = Message(root, text="RED", relief=FLAT).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)` means `label` will be `None` and not the label you want. Instead, do `label = Message(…); label.grid(…)`

Answer (score 0):

From http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/message.htm

> "A multi-line text message."

Width is measured in characters I believe, so your text was getting justified strangely.
I replaced the calls to `Message()` with `Label()`, and removed the sticky arguments.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry

root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text="RED", relief="flat").grid(row=0,column=0)
Red = Entry(root, borderwidth=1).grid(row=0,column=1)

label = Label(root, text="BLUE", relief="flat",).grid(row=1,column=0)
Blue = Entry(root, borderwidth=1,).grid(row=1,column=1)

label = Label(root, text="GREEN", relief="flat").grid(row=2,column=0)
Green = Entry(root, borderwidth=1,).grid(row=2,column=1)

label = Label(root, text="LIGHT ID", relief="flat").grid(row=3,column=0)
LightNum = Entry(root, borderwidth=1,).grid(row=3,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

If you really want to keep using `Message()`:

```
label = Message(root, text="GREEN", relief="flat", aspect=200).grid(row=2,column=0)
Green = Entry(root, borderwidth=1,).grid(row=2,column=1)
```

> aspect= Aspect ratio, given as the width/height relation in percent.
>   The default is 150, which means that the message will be 50% wider
>   than it is high. Note that if the width is explicitly set, this option
>   is ignored. (aspect/Aspect)

Comment: Please remove the wrong usage pointed out by @SyntaxVoid from your answer.